# Creating a Large Matrix in ff

Tags: r

I am trying to create a huge matrix in ff, and I know that ff is good for this sort of thing.

But, there is a major problem. The dimensions of the matrix exceed .Machine$max_integer! I am running on a 64 bit machine, using 64bit R and 64bit ff.

Is there any way to get around this problem?

It's been suggested that R is using the MAXINT value from stdint.h. Is there any way to fix this without changing that file and possibly breaking build?

```
> ffMatrix <- ff(vmode="boolean", dim=c(300000,300000))
Error in if (length < 0 || length > .Machine$integer.max) stop("length must be between 1 and .Machine$integer.max") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In ff(vmode = "boolean", dim = c(300000, 300000)) :
  NAs introduced by coercion

> 300000**2 > .Machine$integer.max
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: do you know how large this matrix is? 86.7361738 exabytes [so you need 128 bit processor]. :-) memory is cheap but not that cheap

Comment: Oh that was just an example to see if I got an error. My matrix is about 300000x300000.

Comment: that still very large matrix, you need parallel computer :-).

300000x300000 > 2^32 (int is likely to be 32 bits, even on 64-bit  machine)

Comment: True. bigmemory can handle it, but the file is 117GB as a dense matrix. Right now there is a void in R: out-of-memory huge sparse matrices.

Comment: well, such applications are few overall. try to think algorithm differently maybe? Good luck

Comment: aaa: Copy/paste the third comment "that still very large matrix, you need parallel computer..." as an answer and I will mark it best. After researching, that is correct, there is no "long long" in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is still a very large matrix, you would need a parallel computer :-). 300000x300000 > 2^32 (int is likely to be 32 bits, even on 64-bit machine) .

See also this [link](http://tech.slashdot.org/story/10/05/02/2038255/MATLAB-Cant-Manipulate-64-Bit-Integers)